# How to share firebase login between all activities?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create share class for accessing firebase authentication between all activities. It also have to handle creating and destroying listener for authentication. So far I wrote this, but I am not sure, that this is best approach - I am afraid of memory leak and issues with ensuring, that class has been set and listener created and destroyed.

```
public class User {

private static boolean loginPassed = false;
private static String userUid = null;

private static FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

//MUST BE CALLED FROM ALL ACTIVITIES BEFORE TRY TO ACCESS GETTER/SETTER = SOURCE OF POSSIBLE ISSUES
private static void initUser()
{
    if (!loginPassed)
    {
        //FIREBASE LOGIN
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    userUid = user.getUid();
                    loginPassed = true;
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };

        //START LISTENER
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
}

public static String getUserUid() {
    return userUid;
}

public static void setUserUid(String userUid) {
    User.userUid = userUid;
}

//HOW TO STOP LISTENER AFTER USER CLOSE ALL ACTIVITIES
private static void stopListener()
{
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking for here, but every Activity in your app can independently listen for signing and signout events through its own `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`.  This is the standard practice, so they can each react to that state when it happens.

I think it's not a good idea to try to maintain a global state for the signed in user like this.  If everything just uses the listener, they can be notified of changes in state.  You don't want to make any assumptions.  Adjust the state of the UI for the Activity according to those events, as they are received.

It's also not clear to me why you would want to create a new user every time they appear to be logged out.  Creating a new account should be something that's part of UI interactions that you control, so the user can choose whether or not they're logged in or logged out.

Comment: I wanted to avoid login user x-times (when he start activity A,B,C). Each time it login, which doesn´t seem to be effective solution. So idea was to login only once for whole application. I have to use anonymous login, this is why user have to be always logged.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson "I think it's not a good idea to try to maintain a global state for the signed in user like this". Can you please provide an official link regarding the statement you made?

Comment: @RedM It's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you try to do. Let me try to read your code:

- You check if the user passed the login running the static method, case 1: not passed

  - create an `AuthStateListener()` which logs a message whenever the authentication state changed
  - start this listener, listener says that user is not signed in yet
  - create now a new user with email and password which are never declared or defined, how should this work?
  - if user is created, set `loginPassed` to true, if not toast a message to user at the EmailAndPasswordActivity, what doesn't automatically mean that this activity is running, since you want to run this method also from other activities
  - that's all? Where is the user signin part? When does the `userId` change?
- Lets see the case where the `loginPassed`is true:

  - nothing.

So that means that you want to create a new user, what is not possible without parsing email and password, whenever the `loginPassed` is false. Ok. That means that everytime you start or restart your app you create a new user, because the `loginPassed`is set to false.

What you should normally do is:

- Create a new user when the user wants to create a new user and tell you his email address and a password
- Login the user when he is not logged in. This is checked every single time an activity needs a logged in user. That means your `OnAuthStateChanged` listener is started on every activity separately (and get stopped `onStop()` method) and checks if the user is logged in, if not, start an login interface to login with email and password through the listener.

  - if successful logged in restart the previous activity which opened the login interface.
  - if not successful logged in handle the case, close the app or ask again for email and password.

It's a **bad practice** to save the unique user id to the device permanent. The user still be logged in after the app is closed and reopened again, so storing the user id doesn't make sense. You must run `mAuth.signOut()` to sign out. To get more clearance about how you should use the firebase methods, listeners and so on, read the Firebase documentation and watch some tutorials on Youtube. Try to understand exactly how and when each part of the user login session is started, changed and stopped to get a perfect use of it.

I hope I explain it clear enough and I hope I didn't say something wrong, I keep learning too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by loggin user in application singleton. Why?

1) Because user must be signed in whole time.

2) Each login made by activity slow down UI response, because depending actions 
can´t be done before. I am not talking about 1ms, but 100-200 ms each time activity starts, if it is implemented there.

I didn´t save user password. After Firebase sing in, application keep credentials by itself, by desing.